# list in python is empty

Tags: python, list

```
m = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
n = list(range(1,5))
l = zip(m,n)
x = list(l)
print(x)
print(list(l))
```

The second `print` is an empty list. Why?

Why not get the same output as the first `print`?

Comment: In Python 3 `zip` objects are generators. Once used they are exhausted.

Comment: Specifically, `x = list(l)` exhausts the generator `l`. Then, when you try to reuse `l`, the data you get is nothing. If the final line was `print(list(zip(m, n)))`, it work work, because that would be a *new* generator. See the dupe this question was closed against for more detail.

Comment: zip() returns an iterator, more like you use index while iterating through loops. Outside the loop, you cant access the index/iterator. For more info and examples, you can read through the docs -https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip returns an iterator. Once you consume the iterator then it will continue to return empty.

> If you consume the iterator with list(), then you’ll see an empty list as well.

https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/